# MySQL Two User Database Consolidation

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am redesigning a database and I need some help.

I have two "User" tables, `USER` and `APPLETCUST`, with one being an internal user and the other being a customer.

Since I want them both to login to the same area, I *think* I need to create a new table that holds login information and whether or not the person is a `USER` or an `APPLETCUST` and then have a relationship to the respective `USER` or `APPLETCUST` to get that information.

What do you think? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend merging the table, but you already suggested it yourself :-) Creating a third table that references the two tables is also possible but might get messy unless you write the constraints properly.

Comment: I wish I could merge the tables, but unfortunately the "person with the ideas" does not want to.

Comment: Then simply make a table `(id,user_id,appletcust_id)` where one of those two may be `NULL` but not both and not none (constraint).